# echo variable into input type checkbox value displaying empty even though I confirm it has value

Tags: php, input

I am displaying row_id and checkboxes so the user can check which row to export from the database.

I confirm that $row_id has value because it does display on the screen immediately before I try to use the  command.

The checkboxes also appear and the user is able to check them.

After clicking SUBMIT, I display the count of check_list[] and the value of check_list[]. Interestingly, the count displays a value of 2 indicating correctly that the user checked 2 boxes, but the value is not being captured or displayed.

Here is the code that I am having trouble with. The value is displaying blank instead of the value of $row_id.

```
$row_id = $row['id'];
echo '<td>'. $row_id ;
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo !empty($row_id)?$row_id;?>" ';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying to print the value is not the correct way. You are trying to `echo` a string and expecting PHP to execute inside a string. You have to **Concatenate** the value and string to get it working. Try below

```
$row_id = '10';
echo '<td>'. $row_id ;
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="'.$row_id .'" ';
```

Also, if you want the checkbox to present only if the value is not empty then do below

```
$row_id = '10';
echo '<td>'. $row_id ;
if(!empty($row_id)) { 
   echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="'.$row_id .'" ';
}
```

Hope this helps!